# Missing parent page attribute

Tags: pages, page-specific-settings

Suddenly the parent page attribute is missing on the page edit view. I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 and the newest Avada theme. The parent attribute has worked. Now it is not shown as page attribute. I've updated Wordpress and the theme. It has not helped. I have switched the theme and set Avada back again and it worked for a short time. Now do not again.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted the theme author about this, as it seems to be theme related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself. The Drop-down list is only displayed if there is at least one public page. Why there is not just "There is no public page" text instead of hiding the list without a hint!?

I have set every page to private, so that the list was not displayed at all. If I have made a page ​​public, I could select it as a page attribute of a new created page.

Comment: Glad you solved this - feel free to mark this answer as accepted, you can do that with your own answers too :)

Answer (score 0):

The last answer was totally correct for me. I have made a page public and the parent page attribute came back. I would also ad something : you need to make public the parent page you want to determine. If your parent page is not public, you won't be able to select it. 
Something I find totally weird.

Thanks a lot for helping !